# geom_point points manual scaling

Tags: r, plot, scaling

I got some data (named result.df) which looks like the following:

```
    orgaName                  abundance          pVal         score        
     A                        3          9.998622e-01     1.795338e-04
     B                        2          9.999790e-01     1.823428e-05
     C                        1          2.225074e-308    3.076527e+02
     D                        1          3.510957e-01     4.545745e-01
```

and so on...

What I am now plotting is this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(result.df, aes(log2(abundance), (1-pVal), label=orgaName)) +
   ylab("1 - P-Value")+
   xlab("log2(abundance)")+
   geom_point(aes(size=score))+
   ggtitle(colnames(case.count.matrix)[i])+
   geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05),hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2.5)+       
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.95), colour="blue", linetype="dashed")+
   theme_classic()
```

Everything works fine and looks rather fine. However, what I would like is to scale the point size introduced through

```
geom_point(aes(size=score))+
```

to be scaled against fixed values. So the legend should scale in a decadic logarithm but the score should stay the same. Such that low scores nearly disappear and large scores are kind of comparable with respect to their point size between different "result.df".

*EDIT*

After checking on the comments of @roman and  @vrajs5 I was able to produce a plot like this [image: new plot].
Using the following code:

```
   ggplot(result.df, aes(log2(abundance), (1-pVal), label=orgaName)) +
   ylab("1 - P-Value")+
   xlab("log2(abundance)")+
   geom_point(aes(size=score))+
   ggtitle(colnames(case.count.matrix)[i])+    
   #geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05 & log2(abundance) > xInt),hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2.5)+
   geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05),hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2.5)+
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.95), colour="blue", linetype="dashed")+
   #geom_vline(aes(xintercept=xInt), colour="blue", linetype="dashed")+
   #geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal > 0.05 & log2(abundance) > xInt),alpha=.5,hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2)+
   #geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05 & log2(abundance) < xInt),alpha=.5,hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2)+
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_size(range=c(2,12),expand=c(2,0),breaks=c(0,1,10,100,1000,1000000),labels=c(">=0",">=1",">=10",">=100",">=1000",">=1000000"),guide="legend")
```

As you can see, the breaks are introduced and labeled as intendet. However the point size in the legend does not reflect the point sizes in the plot. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can adjust [scale_size](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_size.html) by specifying breaks, limits, labels...

Comment: The range parameter controls the size of the points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Roman mentioned, if you use scale_size you can specify the limits on size..

Following is the example how to control size of points

```
result.df = read.table(text = 'orgaName                  abundance          pVal         score        
A                        3          9.998622e-01     1.795338e-04
B                        2          9.999790e-01     1.823428e-05
C                        1          2.225074e-308    3.076527e+02
D                        1          3.510957e-01     4.545745e-01
E                        3          2.510957e-01     2.545745e+00
F                        3          1.510957e-02     2.006527e+02
G                        2          5.510957e-01     3.545745e-02', header = T)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(result.df, aes(log2(abundance), (1-pVal), label=orgaName)) +
  ylab("1 - P-Value")+
  xlab("log2(abundance)")+
  geom_point(aes(size=score))+
  #ggtitle(colnames(case.count.matrix)[i])+
  geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05),hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2.5)+       
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.95), colour="blue", linetype="dashed")+
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_size(range = c(2,12))
```

Output graph is
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, but maybe I did not state my problem clear enough. If I now want to plot another result.df (containing different values) the largest point might not indicate a score of 300 but rathern one of 3000, say. What I want is a fixed legend for the scores which makes (at least somewhat) the dot sizes comparable through different plots. Is that also possible with range? At the moment I am trying this by adding a manual scale like this: `continuous_scale(breaks=c("0","1","10","100","1000"),labels=c("0","1","10","100","1000"),scale_name="Score")` but it does not work atm.

Comment: Yes using scale_size range and breaks can make sure that points are plotted well. But you have to make sure you set parameters according to input set.

Comment: hmm I don't quite get it yet... I edited the original question but can't fix the dot size problem in the legend...

Comment: That is maybe the big problem. The values of the score parameter vary from result.df to result.df . Sometimes all the scores range from 1 to 100. Sometimes they range from 1 to over 1 million.

Answer (score 0):

I see the thread has not been completely solved, here is my contribution.

I faced the same problem, the answer has been partially given by Roman Luštrik.

Indeed, all you have to do is using scale_size() with both the scale and the limit arguments.

Using previous exemple, but adjusting it to your range of value :

```
result.df = read.table(text = 'orgaName                  abundance          pVal         score        
A                        3          9.998622e-01     1.795338e-04
B                        2          9.999790e-01     1.823428e-05
C                        1          2.225074e-308    3.076527e+02
D                        1          3.510957e-01     4.545745e-01
E                        3          2.510957e-01     2.545745e+00
F                        3          1.510957e-02     2.006527e+02
G                        2          5.510957e-01     3.545745e-02', header = T)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(result.df, aes(log2(abundance), (1-pVal), label=orgaName)) +
  ylab("1 - P-Value")+
  xlab("log2(abundance)")+
  geom_point(aes(size=score))+
  #ggtitle(colnames(case.count.matrix)[i])+
  geom_text(data=subset(result.df, pVal < 0.05),hjust=.65, vjust=-1.2,size=2.5)+       
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=.95), colour="blue", linetype="dashed")+
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_size(range = c(2,10), limits = c(1,1000000)
```

[image]

Of course, having such a wide scale (1 to 1000000) will not render very nicely as you can't have a size scale where the last circle is 1000000 bigger than the first one.

For this, I suggest to create a new column in the original table, and compute log10(score), then apply the same logic but with these values instead.